Wrap a range defined by raw pointers into a proper iterator
I have a question on iterators: I have to interface some old C-style API using raw pointers within some tree class. In short, each node maintains two pointers denoting the range of (potentially available) children. It is guaranteed that these children live in some continuous part of memory (lets say a std::vector). Unfortunately, these pointers may be nullptr (most obviously because the node is a leaf).
Now - I try to achieve something very simple: I want to hide those raw pointer from the user of the class and rather provide some iterator. The caller should not be required to check the node for being a leaf beforehands - the iterator should be able to handle this.
I have come up with something that seems to work but as I have never tried myself out in writing custom iterators, I better ask for support here.
What I am not sure about is my way of handling the nullptr within ChildrenIterator. I am also not sure about operator++. I decided to check for the end iterator but maybe this is paranoia?
I am a little afraid that I overlook something very basic here that I simply dont know.
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    Node(int x, bool isLeaf = false) : _data{x}, _isLeaf{isLeaf} {}

    bool isLeaf() const { return _isLeaf; }

    class ChildrenIterator {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = Node;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = Node*;
        using reference = Node&;

        ChildrenIterator(Node* beg, Node* end) : _beg{beg}, _end{end} 
        {
        }

        const Node& operator*() const {
            if (_beg == _end || !_beg) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Illegal dereference of end ChildrenIterator");
            }
            return *_beg;
        }
        ChildrenIterator& operator++() {
            if (_beg != _end && _beg != nullptr)
                _beg++;
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(const ChildrenIterator& a, const ChildrenIterator& b) { return a._beg == b._beg && a._end == b._end; }
        friend bool operator!=(const ChildrenIterator& a, const ChildrenIterator& b) { return not (a == b); }

    private:
        Node* _beg;
        Node* _end;
    };

    ChildrenIterator begin() { 
        auto* beg = isLeaf() ? nullptr : _children;
        auto* end = isLeaf() ? nullptr : _childrenEnd; 
        return ChildrenIterator{beg, end}; 
    }
    ChildrenIterator end() { 
        auto* beg = isLeaf() ? nullptr : _childrenEnd;
        auto* end = isLeaf() ? nullptr : _childrenEnd; 
        return ChildrenIterator{beg, end}; 
    }

    int _data{42};
    Node* _children{nullptr};
    Node* _childrenEnd{nullptr};
    bool _isLeaf{false};
};
 
int main()
{
    Node children[5] = {Node{1}, Node{2}, Node{3}, Node{4}, Node{5}};
    Node parent{42};
    parent._children = children;
    parent._childrenEnd = children + 5;
    for (const auto& n : parent) {
        std::cout << "Hello from: " << n._data << std::endl;
    }

    Node leaf{43, true};
    for (const auto& n : leaf) {
        std::cout << "Hello from: " << n._data << std::endl;
    }
}


"I am a little afraid that I overlook something very basic" - You have, so your intuition was correct. +1 for that. Read up on the rule of 0/3/5.

You should also add operator++(int) to support post-increment. Apart from this, I don't see anything wrong with your iterator.

@TedLyngmo ChildrenIterator seems to happily follow the rule of 0. What do you believe is the problem with it?

@IgorTandetnik I'm thinking of Node but it may not be a problem unless deletion of the tree is done on both the original nodes and any copies made on those nodes. I'd make copying impossible just to make sure and implement moves.

It's not clear why you need a custom iterator to begin with. Everything works just fine with Node* for iterator.

@Igor Tandetnik I continued reading on the iterator topic and after a while a asked myself the very same question. In the end, a pointer into a linear container is nothing but an iterator. I added sorting to the tiny example (https://godbolt.org/z/zjM4dsa3M) and it works just fine.
As long as I do not need a more complicated iteration, I will stick with returning pointers and rely on the convention that nobody dereferences the iterator it without checking it != end().
